# Concatenate issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

When I want to use `CONCATENATE` in SQL Server:

```
CONCAT(year(dateadd(year, -1, left(t1.[FQuater], 4))), right(t1.[FFQuater], 2))
```

I get this error:

[image]

Column `FQuater` is of `Varchar` datatype.

Comment: `CONCAT` was introduced with SQL Server 2012. Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Doesn't YEAR return an integer?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `+` which is available on older versions of SQL Server instead of `concat` which is only available from SQL Server 2012:

```
 year(dateadd(year,-1,left(t1.[FQuater],4))) +''+ right(t1.[FFQuater],2)
```

To avoid nulls(if possible)

```
 isnull(year(dateadd(year,-1,left(t1.[FQuater],4))),'') +''+ isnull(right(t1.[FFQuater],2),'')
```

EDIT: As @ravish.hacker mentioned, you can do it like this:

```
 isnull(year(dateadd(year,-1,left(t1.[FQuater],4))),'') +''+ isnull(right(t1.[FFQuater],2),'') + ' '
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Can you try this on example date like '20100101' and see what result you get? Also if you can please share the result here.

Comment: Try this here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/5896
its or just try SELECT GETDATE() + '' + GETDATE() you will see what i mean. While @4est in his question expects it to concatenate. Not arithmetically add the dates.

Comment: Irrespective, it is still not concatenation what you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Hoping you are using SQL Server 2012 or later.

Concat by itself is nothing. You need to use select or set.

For example.

```
Select CONCAT(year(dateadd(year,-1,left(t1.[FQuater],4))),right(t1.[FFQuater],2))
```

For SQL Server 2008 this will work:

```
DECLARE @FQuater NVARCHAR(100) = '20110826'

SELECT CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, LEFT(@FQuater, 4))) AS NVARCHAR) + CAST(RIGHT(@FQuater, 2) AS NVARCHAR)
```

Comment: I have it into my select statment, I just put some Concat code

Comment: Sorry missed the fact that you are using sql2008. It won't work.

Comment: Let me rephrase your query for sql2008 and put it here.

Comment: thanks you ravish!

Comment: @4est How come this answer got approved when he updated his post to the same answer(which will be slower due to conversion!) as mine after I already posted mine?

Comment: you have right Sagi, single '+' is better

Comment: @4est Two things: 1. Conversion will happen anyway. Implicit or Explicit. Its better to do it yourself. 2. Try the solution, it is giving different answer.